# Azure CDN using root domain solution

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have a concern with our CDN as we are planning to apply custom domain. I understand the part that it is not possible to map a CNAME record to a root domain, such as contoso.com. I want to ask for a workaround, let us say yes we already assigned it to www.contoso.com. But people now adays do not use the www subdomain anymore and will just type constoso.com in the URL address bar and therefore it will just return a 404 because it is not mapped making as lose potential customers. What is your suggested solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

Some DNS hosts allow creating CNAMES for root domains (ANAMES). 
If your DNS host doesn't allow that then you can try to use subdomain redirection (like simple node.js app hosted on azure). Not the best solution but I'm not sure if other exists.

Comment: Thanks. that's what i did. Godaddy does not provide CNAMES for root domains

Answer (score 4):

The work around is to use the cdnverify CNAME feature with A record.

```
CNAME   : cdnverify.constoso.com -> cdnverify.constoso.azureedge.net
A record: constoso.com -> x.x.x.x
```

After all verification is complete, the CNAME can be removed. It worked for my domain.

(source: https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/adding-a-root-domain-to-azure-cdn-endpoint/)

Comment: Which IP adresse are you using for the A record then?

Comment: This only works in combination with an Alias (ANames). When using Azure DNS, you can create an alias and point it to the CDN resource and remove the @ records.

Comment: You need to select "Alias record set" in Azure in order to create the link to the Azure resource that you want. This will do the "same thing" as creating the CNAME at the root.

Comment: Can anyone show how to do this in GoDaddy?

Comment: This no longer works. In the CDN when you try to enabling https on your custom domain, it shows an error saying "Enabling Https with CDN Managed Certificate is not supported anymore for apex (root) domains."

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no solution for this, except the described workaround when your domain-provider supports this.

There is a feature request on Azure for this problem:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/2566744a-8626-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

Comment: the link returns 404