# Using Microsoft Blob Storage Static Website, and a CDN with Custom Domain; how does one use non www?

Tags: azure, azure-static-website-hosting

I have been developing several static websites which I host as blob storage static websites. I then use Azure CDN with custom domains.

While this works when I use www. with my custom domain, it does not work without it. For example ->
[www.tommcclean.me](http://www.tommcclean.me) (works)
tommcclean.me (doesn't work)

Naturally this is because it uses a CNAME mapping, Ideally I need to setup an A record but I can't find an IP to give it.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure CDN using root domain solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198859/azure-cdn-using-root-domain-solution)

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately not; none of the DNS providers I am using support alias A-Name records (Namecheap/123reg/BlueHost)

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I know of: You can switch your DNS name servers over to [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns).

You then have two options:

- Use CNAME as suggested in the sample
- Use [alias records](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-alias-records-for-azure-dns/) to point the domain directly to your CDN